# Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant

I cloned this project :

> https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/tree/master/k8s-vagrant

And when i try to execute :

> vagrant up

I'm getting this error :

```
==> k8s-master: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    k8s-master: Installing Ansible...
#<Thread:0x00005640f31cd010@/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:71 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    111: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    110: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
    109: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `call'
    108: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:592:in `lock'
    107: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in `block in action'
    106: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
    105: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    104: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    103: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    102: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    101: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    100: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
     99: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     98: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     97: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     96: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     95: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     94: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     93: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     92: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     91: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     90: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
     89: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     88: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     87: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     86: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
     85: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     84: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     83: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     82: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     81: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     80: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     79: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     78: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     77: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     76: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
     75: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     74: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
     73: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     72: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
     71: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     70: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
     69: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     68: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
     67: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
     66: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     65: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
     64: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     63: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
     62: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     61: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     60: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     59: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
     58: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     57: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
     56: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     55: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:79:in `call'
     54: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     53: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     52: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     51: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     50: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     49: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     48: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     47: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     46: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     45: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     44: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     43: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     42: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     41: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     40: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     39: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     38: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     37: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     36: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     35: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     34: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     33: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     32: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     31: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     30: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     29: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
     28: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     27: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
     26: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     25: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
     24: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     23: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
     22: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     21: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:103:in `call'
     20: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:103:in `each'
     19: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:126:in `block in call'
     18: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:126:in `call'
     17: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:504:in `hook'
     16: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     15: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     14: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     13: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     12: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     11: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     10: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `call'
      9: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:138:in `run_provisioner'
      8: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/provisioners/ansible/provisioner/guest.rb:19:in `provision'
      7: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/provisioners/ansible/provisioner/guest.rb:54:in `check_and_install_ansible'
      6: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:43:in `capability'
      5: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
      4: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
      3: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/ubuntu/ansible_install.rb:14:in `ansible_install'
      2: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/ubuntu/ansible_install.rb:22:in `ansible_apt_install'
      1: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:267:in `sudo'
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:257:in `execute': The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. (Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError)
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

But whatever i do :

> apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties

This does not fix the issue.

How could i fix the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that the package [does not appear in their playbook](https://github.com/sayems/kubernetes.resources/blob/master/k8s-vagrant/roles/components/tasks/main.yml#L8-L12), and is [not a package in bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-software-properties), I believe the answer to your question is "don't do that". Also, 8 months is an **eternity** in kubernetes time, so you will be better off using [a certified distribution](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.11.0/docs/vagrant.md#introduction) and not some random user's repo

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this error. After so many tries and trying everything over here [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422975/e-package-python-software-properties-has-no-installation-candidate?newreg=ac1521ccd390420e972850d6842b03b8)
I opened `install-deps` in `vi` and run this command

```
:%s/python-software-properties/python3-software-properties/g
```

save the file and re-run the script. My problem was solved.